# Gparted not detecting controller after removing a drive

Tags: linux, hp-proliant, raid-controller

Ran into a weird scenario.

Installed 5 hotswap HDD drives on a HP SmartArray P410 RAID controller running RAID-5. Went into Gparted and created different partitions. Realized one of the drives was faulty. Removed it. Rebooted into Gparted. It now cannot detect the controller at all, saying 'cannot find /dev/cciss/c0d0' - basically it cannot access the controller(my best guess).

However, it shows the previous allocated space based on the 5 hard drive setup. However, now there are only four hard drives. Not sure what's going on. Can't touch anything on those 4 drives through Gparted(it keeps saying cannot access c0d0).The 5th HDD is not functional. I haven't tried putting it back in, but not sure how to proceed basically. Should I recreat the logical drive? If so, what would be the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't make sense...

If you had an HP logical drive comprised of 5 disks and one 1 disk failed, the array/logical drive size would still be that of the 5 drives. It just means that your array is running in degraded mode (because you've removed a disk).

Put the disk back in.

It wasn't faulty at the time you configured an array on it. Why do you believe it's faulty now?

Accepted comment in the accepted answer: The P410 is an enterprise controller. For the OP, just reboot and hit F8 when prompted to configure the controller. Create a new array with 4 disks and be done with it.

Comment: Because it has a red LED light and is making crigeworthy noises.

Comment: If I put the disk back in, it is stuck on the boot screen for some reason. My first check was the HDD.

Comment: Well, a P410 controller can indicate any HP ProLiant server built between 2009 and early 2012... So if your server is under warranty, you can obtain a replacement drive... And go from there.

Comment: It's an old test server. Out of warranty and neglected. I'm not even Ops or Devops, I'm just trying to salvage it's functionality. So total n00b in enterprise servers. Is there a way to go with just the 4? I don't care if every bit of data is lost, I just want to get this up and running.

Comment: Is the P410 (if it is a P410..?) one of those fakeraid controllers (like the intel "RAID" controllers) where Linux distros ignore the fakeraid and show the individual disks?

Comment: @MarkHenderson The P410 is an enterprise controller. For the OP, just reboot and hit F8 when prompted to configure the controller. Create a new array with 4 disks and be done with it.